# Is there a way to add a picture on top of our list view using the modern UI

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, modern-experience

Inside classic layout i can edit the list view page and add a web part to show an image on top of the list fields as follow:-

[image]

but if i switch to modern UI i will lose the ability to edit the list view page. so my question is how i can show a picture above the list fields (above the "+ New Item link")inside modern UI? is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Which web part are you using to add a picture in classic experience?

Comment: @Ganesh Sanap using the script editor web part

Answer (score 0):

Modern UI page is disallowed to edit and it does not have a master page. If it's a custom site page, you can use [modern script editor webpart](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/blob/master/samples/react-script-editor/README.md)

Another possible way is to use spfx extension to inject css/JS:

- https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/step-by-step-procedure-to-add-a-js-file-to-all-pages-in-a-spfx-modern-pages-using-sharepoint-framework-extension/

Comment: i can not add the modern script editor webpart inside allitems.aspx list view page, also i do not want to inject css/js i want to show a picture inside the list view page only and not inside all pages